# API target and min confusion

Tags: android

I am confused about the target build and sdk usage

Lets say I have this code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
 //do xyz
}
```

Let say that I built against API 19 (kitkat) and my target api in manifest is 19 and my minimum supported api is 9

Now if a device with API 9 runs the above code, will it crash? I expect the answer is yes becasuse it will not understand what Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT means. However, what's the point of the check above then in first place?

Please help clarify this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't crash. Simply the code within the if won't be executed. `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT` is a constant field, and as you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), the constant fields are replaced with the numbers themselves by the compiler.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I didn't know about compiler replacing it with number before it runs on the machine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

lesser versions of android will use the support library, if the check for kit-kat fails, it will revert to the closest possibkle form that version supports.... via the support library...
you cannot run you app on anything less than the minimum version, but it will find a way to run with less than the target version as long as its aboe the minimum

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't crash, because its Build.VERSION.SDK_INT value is 9. It simply will not enter inside your if clause. Only devices that have API version 19 or above will run your code inside the if. Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT is equal to 19.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted won't crash because the class `Build` is created and compiled for every build of your app (as the `R` file) depending of the target API you set in the manifest

As you setup your target API to 19, the `Build` class will contain the field `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT` because it exists starting from API level 19.